# JPA criteria query group by return a map

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have Test and Result entities:

```
class Result{
   ...
   private Test test;
   ...
}

class Test{
   ...
   private List<Result> results;
   ...
}
```

And I need to group results by test (`Map<Test, List<Result>`) but using Criteria API. Can anyone help me with it?